# ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_bz2)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to use `import bz2`, but I got the following error,

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_bz2)
```

I think `bz2` is a `python` standard lib.

I am using a `Python3.6.4` virtual environment on `CentOS 7`, I am wondering how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the version of your python is too high, I use  python2.7, and it is ok;